# U-value for suspended ground floor

Tags: energy-efficiency, thermal-conduction, thermal-insulation

I'm about to finish U-value calculation for a house (an assignment for the Sustainable Technology for Buildings module) but I can't understand the formula. I've got all the data except from "ln" (underlined in the screenshot below). Can anyone help with it? A - 59.00m²; B - 38.51m; h - 0.02m; w - 370mm;
[image]

Comment: Ln is usually log and ln is natural log. Surely it is in the module notes somewhere…

Comment: It is actually defined in the standard [ISO 80000-2](https://www.iso.org/standard/64973.html).